# Is it required to list each cookie by name to comply with EU/UK Cookie Laws?

Tags: cookie, eu-cookie-law

Some sites appear to list each cookie exhaustively, others (the majority) state only how they are used, and how a user may clear them.

Do you need to list each cookie by name, together with what it does and how it expires? (This question is specific to UK sites)

Answer (score 5):

It is required by EU law that all websites operating in or targetting audiences in the EU must have a cookie notice. When they first introduced the policy, it was a strict consent, since then it has changed to notice only. So simply displaying a notice message to users complys with this non-sense law.

Comment: And that notice does not have to include a list of the cookies, their purpose and expiration dates?

Comment: No, you do not need to... the only part you must do is `inform users that cookies are not being used to gather information unnecessarily.` How you demonstrate this is up to you. So you can either say we collect information because, or we do not collect information such as, or simply link to the cookies you do use etc etc.

Comment: What? A non-sense law? No! Say it ain't so. What has this world come to? Prior to today, I have never heard of such a thing. I am shocked! Cheers!!

Comment: ....an end. well, at least the sanity part of this world. I do have to hand it to EU because some people like to store secret information on people's computers through cookies thereby tracking the user's actions which then later can cause customized advertising to appear on the user's screen and more mess. Cookies are very powerful.

Comment: glad I have seen someone who says (like me) that it is nonsense. Instead user should know to use VPN or whatever if they are so afraid of internet world, websites and conspiracy theories.  If i am hidden refugee or target, then i should know to use VPN, and not such dull to have a need to be educated by cookie messages.